# Can someone help identify this piece? Looks like the back of a tiny dump truck

Tags: part-identification

[image]

It's the big gray flat piece, if anyone can help find this piece I would appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score 16):

It appears to be [Bionicle Krana Holder 3 x 4 (Scoop / Bucket with Axle Hole)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=42042)

Comment: As someone that owns many Bionicle, I agree - that is what that piece is